# assign default value to DateTime property in table entity of azure storage table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

How can I assign default value to DateTime property in table entity of Azure Storage Table.

I am trying the code below, but I'm not able to set value (throwing an error from Azure Table while inserting, as DateTime taking has 1/1/0001).

```
[DefaultValue(DateTime.Now]

public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Aravind in the answer, minimum value for `DateTime` type attribute supported by Azure Tables is `Jan 1, 1600 UTC`. Thus setting the default value to `DateTime.MinValue` will result in an error.

One possible solution for you is to keep this attribute `nullable` in your model.

```
public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
```

So, when no value is supplied the default value for this would be null. You would need to remove `DefaultValue` attribute as mentioned in comments above.

Comment: Even Datetime is not allowing null in azure Table, throwing can't be null error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using? I have used nullable date/time fields with Azure Tables and it is certainly allowed. My guess is that something else is going on with your code.

Answer (score 2):

As Per msdn, the value that can go in datetime property is "A 64-bit value expressed as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The supported DateTime range begins from 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC. The range ends at December 31, 9999."

So you cannot assign DateTime.MinValue. Lowest you can store is new DateTime(1601, 1, 1)

Comment: Yes I do understand , min value is 1601/1/1, but my question is how i will assign it from my property in entity model as default value.

Comment: It is just another column in the case of table service. So the way you update other columns you will do it in this column too.

Comment: I am updating that column, but if the value of datetime is empty,default c# object is converting to 1/1/0001(as this is the default vale for datetime in c#), i am getting error while updating/inserting entity to azure table. So i want to set default value for Datetime property in model.

Comment: are you getting error in "TableOperation.Insert" operation ?  In the entity object you need to have code to insert the value into Lastupdate column and remove the DefaultValue attribute in the model for that column. or you can add a set method to that property in the model/entity class. it should set the value at all times.